# Android - How to use HoloTheme with AppCompat v22+

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I don't really like Material design's spinner, and AppCompat doesn't contain the Holo Theme anymore. Should I revert back to AppCompat when it still supported Holo Theme or is there another way ?

Answer (score 0):

With AppCompat v22, if you are using an `AppCompatActivity` you have to use an AppCompat theme.

If you try to use another theme you will receive:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a 
    Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

The only way to use a Holo Theme is to use a lower version.

e.g.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
```